# arangodb nodes connected to multiple others

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm just getting started with arangodb and have gotten to my first real problem:

Is it possible to search for nodes connected to all of multiple others? This seems like a basic operation for a graph db but I just can't think of a solution.

For reference, if we take the 'knows' example graph I want to know which persons know Charlie AND Dave (which should be only Bob)

[knows example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8st0.png) (not allowed to embed images yet)

For now my best guess is to start a traversal for all of the "targets" and reduce and filter the response myself, is this really the only way?

EDIT:
OK, to further specify I have added another connection, eve knows dave too, but should NOT be returned since she does not know charlie

EDIT2:
So far I've come up with this query

```
FOR start IN ['persons/charlie', 'persons/dave']
LET knownBy = (FOR v,e,p IN 1 INBOUND start knows
    RETURN v)
FOR p IN knownBy
    COLLECT person = p
    LET knows = (FOR v IN 1 OUTBOUND person._id knows
        RETURN v._id)
    FILTER knows ALL IN ['persons/charlie', 'persons/dave']
    RETURN person
```

However, this feels a bit unnatural, getting the persons known by 'X' to get the persons that know 'X'... Also, the profiler shows that about a third of the time is used for optimizing the plan, there has to be a better solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

If we take the knows example and only search for two connected vertices you can start a traversal on one target with a depth of 2 and filter that the third vertex on the path has to be the second target, then you can just return the second vertex on the path.

```
FOR v, e, p IN 2 ANY 'persons/charlie' knows
  FILTER p.vertices[2]._id == 'persons/dave'
  RETURN p.vertices[1]
```

If you search for more than two vertices, the following query should work well. It starts a traversal with a depth of 1 and collect every _id of the person neighbors and checks of your targets are all containing in the neighbors.

```
LET targets = ['persons/charlie','persons/dave']

FOR person IN persons
  FILTER targets ALL IN FLATTEN((
    FOR v, e, p IN 1 ANY person._id knows
    RETURN v._id
  ))
  RETURN person
```